# Stacked D3 bar chart with multiple level

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want to create a responsive D3 bar chart using my JSON.

I tried pushing my values into an array and create a bar chart using the same array. But it didn't come out well. I don't know what I am missing.

Can anyone please help me with this?

```
JSON = {
  "Resource 1": {
    "metrics": [
      {
        "2021-04-07": {
          "percent": {
            "avg": 15,
            "max": 30,
            "min": 10
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "2021-04-08": {
          "percent": {
            "avg": 30,
            "max": 50,
            "min": 12
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "2021-04-09": {
          "percent": {
            "avg": 35,
            "max": 60,
            "min": 5
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Resource 2": {
    "metrics": [
      {
        "2021-04-07": {
          "percent": {
            "avg": 30,
            "max": 50,
            "min": 10
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "2021-04-08": {
          "percent": {
            "avg": 15,
            "max": 30,
            "min": 10
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "2021-04-09": {
          "percent": {
            "avg": 27,
            "max": 39,
            "min": 15
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My y-axis will be numeric with a maximum value = 100 and the x-axis will be a date.

1 whole bar = 1 Resource, each resource contains three segments (Minimum, Average, and Maximum) stacked one above the other.

Each date will have multiple resources. When the cursor moved to the minimum value of resource1 in one date, it should highlight all the minimum value of the same resource1 on others dates too.

While moving the cursor to the bar the tooltip should show the resource name with resource value like

**Resource1**

**min: 10**

I have attached my fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/oLqdrymh/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working very well, Where is the problem?

Comment: duplications of min, max and avg labels. Couldn't able to displace resource name in tooltip while hovering instead date is showed.

Comment: You mean it should be one bar per a date, not a couple?